# Missing definition for <polymer-element> core-overlay

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I noticed this when I run my dart app both with 1.7.0-dev4.3 and dev-4.1

```
Missing definition for <polymer-element>, please add the following HTML import at the top of this file: <link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">. (more details)
lib/src/core-overlay/core-overlay-layer.html:10:1
<polymer

-element name="core-overlay-layer">
```

I have not used any `core-overlay-layer` in my app so far and this seems to be one of the `polymer-core` components.

I have just done a clean install of the latest Dart dev SDK with the same result.

Comment: I also get this a lot with all paper- and core-elements but didn't investigate yet but also didn't experience any further problems though.

Comment: I agree that the app runs normally, but the constant presence of the flag is somewhat annoying. Each time one has to check to be sure it is not something else. I hope it can be fix soon.

Comment: Someone ;-) should create a bug report... I'll check tomorrow.